# TimePicker Minimum value Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, minimum, timepicker

I wan't  to use a TimePicker but setting to it a minimum posible value, that the user can't choose other after that value.

Like the DisplayDateStart in DatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Minimum and Maximum properties of TimePicker Control in silverlight to limit the times displayed in drop down menu.

```
startTime.Maximum = endTime;
endTime.Minimum = startTime;
```

here startTime and endTime are two timepickers

Answer (score 0):

In datefield using throw the BlackoutDates

```
MonthlyDatePicker.DisplayDate = new DateTime(2009, 5, 1);

MonthlyDatePicker.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1);

MonthlyDatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2009, 1, 31);
```

or

```
  MonthlyDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new DatePickerDateRange(

    new DateTime(2009, 1, 1),

    new DateTime(2009, 1, 4)

    ));
```

i think i hope its helps to you